# how to store Json data to a array from For each

Tags: azure-logic-apps

i need to get the data from a json using For Each
the condition is that field Expires is not equal to Null and Expires  less than or equal to current data

[image]

[image]

```
[
    {
        "Environment":  "DEV",
        "Application":  "OTHER",
        "Keyvault":  "key-xx-dd",
        "Secret":  "secrect1",
        "Expires":  "2023-10-19T12:51:20+00:00"
    },
    {
        "Environment":  "DEV",
        "Application":  "OTHER",
        "Keyvault":  "key-xx-dd",
        "Secret":  "secrect2",
        "Expires":  null
    },
    {
        "Environment":  "DEV",
        "Application":  "OTHER",
        "Keyvault":  "key-xx-dd",
        "Secret":  "secrect3",
        "Expires":  "2023-10-19T12:51:20+00:00"
    }
]
```

Comment: You’re best to use a filter step for that.

Comment: how to use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get the data from a json using For Each the condition is that field Expires is not equal to Null and Expires less than or equal to current data

I have used the below workflow and got the result.

[image]

[image]

**code:**

```
{
  "definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
      "Data": {
        "inputs": {
          "variables": [
            {
              "name": "Data",
              "type": "string",
              "value": "@{body('Get_blob_content_(V2)')}"
            }
          ]
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "Get_blob_content_(V2)": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "InitializeVariable"
      },
      "Final_Data": {
        "inputs": {
          "variables": [
            {
              "name": "FinalData",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "Data": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "InitializeVariable"
      },
      "For_each": {
        "actions": {
          "Condition": {
            "actions": {
              "Set_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                  "name": "FinalData",
                  "value": "@{items('For_each')}"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "SetVariable"
              }
            },
            "expression": {
              "and": [
                {
                  "not": {
                    "equals": [
                      "@items('For_each')['Expires']",
                      "@null"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "lessOrEquals": [
                    "@items('For_each')['Expires']",
                    "@utcNow()"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "If"
          }
        },
        "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')",
        "runAfter": {
          "Parse_JSON": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "Foreach"
      },
      "Get_blob_content_(V2)": {
        "inputs": {
          "host": {
            "connection": {
              "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
            }
          },
          "method": "get",
          "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('********'))}/content",
          "queries": {
            "inferContentType": true
          }
        },
        "metadata": {
          "**********": "/test/TestDoc.json",
          "*********": "/test/cosmosTestDoc.json"
        },
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "ApiConnection"
      },
      "Html_to_text": {
        "inputs": {
          "body": "<p>@{variables('Data')}</p>",
          "host": {
            "connection": {
              "name": "@parameters('$connections')['conversionservice']['connectionId']"
            }
          },
          "method": "post",
          "path": "/html2text"
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "Final_Data": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "ApiConnection"
      },
      "Parse_JSON": {
        "inputs": {
          "content": "@body('Html_to_text')",
          "schema": {
            "items": {
              "properties": {
                "Application": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "Environment": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "Expires": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "Keyvault": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "Secret": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "Environment",
                "Application",
                "Keyvault",
                "Secret",
                "Expires"
              ],
              "type": "object"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "Html_to_text": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "ParseJson"
      }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {
      "$connections": {
        "defaultValue": {},
        "type": "Object"
      }
    },
    "triggers": {
      "manual": {
        "inputs": {
          "schema": {}
        },
        "kind": "Http",
        "type": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "$connections": {
      "value": {
        "azureblob": {
          "connectionId": "/subscriptions/**********/resourceGroups/yyyyyyyyyy/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob-1",
          "connectionName": "azureblob-1",
          "id": "/subscriptions/************/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureblob"
        },
        "conversionservice": {
          "connectionId": "/subscriptions/***********/resourceGroups/yyyyyyyy/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/conversionservice",
          "connectionName": "conversionservice",
          "id": "/subscriptions/**********/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/conversionservice"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As **@Skin** suggested, you can use Filter but in Filter you can have only one condition like below.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]